# Regular expression value in hex

Tags: regex

I am learning regular expression and trying to understand what value will be matched if the regex represents in hex value.

For example, if I have `^[\\x00-\\xff]{16}`, does this mean that it will match any values from 0-255 for 16 digits long?

I looked on line, can't seem to find the example.

Thanks

Comment: You could run a test for this kind of thing on: http://regexpal.com/ .

Answer (score 2):

The hexadecimal value refers to the *character code* of the string character being matched.  For example, `'A'` in ASCII or UTF-8 is 65, or `x41`.

`^[\x00-\xff]{16}` means to match, anchored at the beginning of the string, exactly 16 characters whose numeric values are between 0 and 255.  If your regex engine isn't multi-byte-character-set-aware, that will mean *any* character, so in that case it's almost identical to `^.{16}`, except that in many regex engines `.` won't match a newline unless a specific option is turned on (`/s` in Perl and Perl-compatible regex).